Why is SE editing suddenly going haywire?
I haven't used SE in several months, and suddenly editing is completely haywire.  Has something changed?  I updated Chrome, cleared cookies, and restarted my laptop.  And I'm running Windows 10.0.19045.  When I try to write in this window, it keeps going inactive and have to click on it after every few words.  When I add tags, I have a split second in which to type a few letters and click on some selection.  When I edit in this window, it's barely usable because after every few keystrokes the edit window goes inactive and pages abruptly scrolls several lines down, so I basically have to cut&paste everything.  It wasn't like this a few months ago.  What the heck is wrong?

I have had some problems as well, though not as extreme as you describe.  Perhaps it would help if you activated the beta version of the v3 edition of MathJax (edit your profile under "Preferences").  That cured many of my issues, though it created a few new problems.

@ryang   Aw, man!  MB is also keeping me from turning off my AdBlocker too.  What did you do?  I need malware protection, but MB seems to keep causing me problems.

@ryang  Thanks for the info!  I will look into uBlock

@ryang  Yep!  I tuned MB off, and everything works great now.  Do you want to post an Answer, and I'll Accept it?

I had the exact same trouble recently, and eventually figured out that the culprit was my desktop browser's Malwarebytes Browser Guard extension. It was also preventing the drop-down menus from staying open, and noticeably slowing down browsing. Curiously, I didn't encounter these surfing issues outside Stack Exchange, and it does take two hands to clap.
Disabling just its 'Ads/Trackers' protection for StackExchange sites worked sporadically, while completely disabling the extension resolved all the problems.
This extension had been working fine for years, and started acting up only recently, so the mess must have been introduced by some recent (automatic) update. If these bugs haven't already been fixed—I haven't re-enabled it to test this—then perhaps some future update will, especially if we submit a report to Malwarebytes.
(Throughout all this, my uBlock Origin ad-blocker—which I hear that Chrome no longer supports—was continually active in the background.)
